# UIGestureRecognizer not consuming taps

Tags: ios5, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIViewController and I am adding subviews to the main view. The main view has a UIGestureRecogniser and each subview also has a UIGestureRecognizer. In interface builder I have checked canceled in view in the attributes inspector so I would expect taps on the subviews to only fire my gestureRecognizerShouldBegin in the subview handler but they are also firing the handler attached to the view they are place on.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be the case?

I guess I could keep a handle to the particular instance of the GestureRecogniser attached to each subview and compare if the event being fired has come from the correct recogniser but this does not seem like the correct solution. Any help would be much appricated.

Edit: This second solution doesn't even work seems like every UIGestureRecogniser conforming to the current gesture is being fired!

Edit:
The best solution I have come up with is,

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
  if([view isEqual:[touch view]] && self.editing)
     return YES;

  return NO;
  }

I would like the Gesture not to receive the touch at all though